# Vue and Firebase Issue: Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have seen this question asked, but with no good answer. I can understand what the issue is, but can't seem to find out how to remedy it. Here is my function:

```
//set JSON content type and CORS headers for the response
response.header('Content-Type','application/json');
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

//respond to CORS preflight requests
if (request.method == 'OPTIONS') {
response.status(204).send('');
}

// pull in firebase
var firebase = require('firebase');

require("firebase/firestore");

let config = {
  // config stuff here
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

// grab doc id from request
var id = request.query.docId;

// declare connection to firestore
var db = firebase.firestore();

// grab user from request
var docRef = db.collection("clients").doc(id);

// grab the users server and id
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {

// grab the account id
var accountId = doc.data().accountId;

// declare master variable that will be returned
var toReturn = [];

// declare variables that will be returned in toReturn
var gpmGames = [];
var cspmGames = [];
var damageGames = [];
var damageToChampionsGames = [];
var damageTakenGames = [];
var wardsGames = [];

db.collection('games')
  .where('accountId', '==', accountId)
  .get()
  .then((res) => {
    var games = res.docs;
    // iterate through games and get averages and totals to return
    games.forEach(function(game) {

      gpmGames.push(game.data().gpm);
      cspmGames.push(game.data().cspm);
      damageGames.push(game.data().damage);
      damageToChampionsGames.push(game.data().damagetochampions);
      damageTakenGames.push(game.data().damagerecieved);
      wardsGames.push(game.data().wards);

    });
  });

  toReturn['gpmGames'] = gpmGames;
  toReturn['cspmGames'] = cspmGames;
  toReturn['damageGames'] = damageGames;
  toReturn['damageToChampionsGames'] = damageToChampionsGames;
  toReturn['damageTakenGames'] = damageTakenGames;
  toReturn['wardsGames'] = wardsGames;

response.status(200).send(toReturn);
});
```

So I understand that my return is being called before everything is done running. How can I fix that? Of course, my return is giving an empty array and I get the error from firebase: Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking it might be a promise issue? Maybe create a helper function?

Comment: I don't see response.end() isn't it needed?

Comment: Ummmm.. I guess it might. I thought that could be used in place of response.send if nothing was to be sent back. Am I wrong in that regard and it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the promise that's returned from this:

```
db.collection('games')
  .where('accountId', '==', accountId)
  .get()
```

This is an asynchronous call, and it returns immediately with a promise that becomes resolved when the work is complete.

You need to use that promise to send the response at the right time:

```
const proimise = db.collection('games')
  .where('accountId', '==', accountId)
  .get()

promise.then(snapshot => {
    // work with the document snapshot here, and send your response
})
.catch(error => {
    // deal with any errors if necessary.
    response.status(500).send(error)
})
```

The way you're sending the response seems OK, you just need to wait till the fetch is done.